# Windows 10 denies creating shortcuts in Start Menu Folder

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts

I want to create a new custom shortcut in the "All Programs" section of the Start Menu in Windows 10 Home.

I know the location for this is

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

But trying to create a shortcut in this folder (or any subfolder for that matter) results in the error message

> Shortcuts cannot be created at this location. Do you want to create it on the Desktop instead?

*(Freely translated from German)*

What do I need to do to create that shortcut?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Right-click on *your* desktop and create the shortcut that you want.
2. After it is created and tested, copy it to `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
3. If necessary, acknowledge the UAC prompt to copy it to that location.

Comment: Works. Thanks. Windows is so weird at times...

Comment: You're welcome.  I think it is simply an oddity regarding Windows security.  The `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` folder is protected  so that you need to have admin privileges before you can modify it.  However, it looks like the Windows capability that allows us to create a shortcut doesn't function with UAC approval, while a simple file copy does.

Answer (score -1):

You need to be logged in as the local administrator to perform such copy paste .

Comment: The other answer suggests that this needn't be the case, care to expand?

Comment: I'm not sure why you people are down voting the answer it's an actual working way instead of the first answer

Comment: Well I only have one account on the machine, and it's administrator and it doesn't work.

Comment: Local admin is different, right click my computer > manage > users and enable the account administrator and set a password login and try that .

Comment: @Elie if you improve your answer with better instructions & more detail that may help a lot...